# How to call a method from one class to another class

Tags: c#, mysql, class, call

hellow im new to this forum. i searched for a day now and i cant find anything to solve my problem

i need to call a function in a class from a form class.
but evrytime i try i get error 'cs0117' 'DBconnection does not contain a definition for insert' 'line 19'

this is my form where i want to call an class with the line 'DBconnection.insert();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class FrmEditUser : Form
    {
        public FrmEditUser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DBconnection.insert();
        }

        private void LblUserName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

this is the class where i wanna get the funcion from

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
//using System.Data.Odbc;             //added libary
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class DBconnection : Form
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        //Constructor
        public void DBConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "tablemembers";
            uid = "******";
            password = "******";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "localhost=" + server + ";" + "tablemembers=" + database + ";" + "******=" + uid + ";" + "******=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }


        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void Insert()
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO tableinfo (name, age) VALUES('John Smith', '33')";

            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Update statement
        public void Update()
        {
            string query = "UPDATE tableinfo SET name='Joe', age='22' WHERE name='John Smith'";

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create mysql command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                //Assign the query using CommandText
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                //Assign the connection using Connection
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                //Execute query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Delete statement
        public void Delete()
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM tableinfo WHERE name='John Smith'";

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Select statement
        public List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
                    list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
                    list[2].Add(dataReader["age"] + "");
                }

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }
        }

        //Count statement
        public int Count()
        {
            string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tableinfo";
            int Count = -1;

            //Open Connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Mysql Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //ExecuteScalar will return one value
                Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                return Count;
            }
            else
            {
                return Count;
            }
        }

        //Backup
        public void Backup()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
                int year = Time.Year;
                int month = Time.Month;
                int day = Time.Day;
                int hour = Time.Hour;
                int minute = Time.Minute;
                int second = Time.Second;
                int millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

                //Save file to C:\ with the current date as a filename
                string path;
                path = "C:\\" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + "-" + millisecond + ".sql";
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysqldump";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", uid, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output;
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                file.WriteLine(output);
                process.WaitForExit();
                file.Close();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to backup!");
            }
        }

        //Restore
        public void Restore()
        {
            try
            {
                //Read file from C:\
                string path;
                path = "C:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
                string input = file.ReadToEnd();
                file.Close();


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysql";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", uid, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;


                Process process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
                process.StandardInput.Close();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to Restore!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you derive the DBConnection class from the Form class?. This class has nothing to do with a Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `DBconnection` class inside `FrmEditUser` constructor, because `insert()` method is not a static method so you can not access it without instantiation

```
 public FrmEditUser()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    DBconnection connect = new DBconnection();
    connect.insert();
 }
```